# ASP.NET MVC regular expression url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

```
var j = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?\//;
```

I want to restrict only one **/** coming at the end of the string. How can I restrict that in the above regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't tell me you are using regular expressions to validate urls when there's the [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) method.

Comment: @drogon, why do you think that this is not an answer? Proposing the right tool for the job seems valid to me.

Answer (score 0):

After the port-part you should have something like:

((match_part)+?(\/(match_part)+?)?)?

This will allow at least one char in each part, and zero or one part first, if one, then zero or one part more. You have to replace match_part with what you actually want to match, I didnt copy your expression since, for example, the hash (#) isn't valid in the url, just at the end